# Populating data from last row in form when creating a new entry

Tags: asp.net, razor-pages, actionresult

I have a form to create new data entries for comments. Creating completely new entries works fine. However, when I have already created one entry for my entity I want to populate the data from the last entry in my form.

I have tried to modify the OnGet action to include the data from the last entry. I copied the OnGet code from the Edit view into the Create view. However, if I do this, the Create page is not displayed anymore.

I have the following model:

```
    public class ProjectComment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }

        public int RAGStatusId { get; set; }
        public RAGStatus RAGStatus { get; set; }

        public string StatusComment { get; set; }
        public string EscalationComment { get; set; }
        public string GeneralComment { get; set; }
        public double? EOQ { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public ProjectComment ()
        {
            this.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
```

The create form Create.cshtml:

```
@page
@model SimpleProjectReporting.Pages.ClientDetails.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>ProjectComment</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectComment.ProjectId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ProjectComment.ProjectId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProjectId"><option value="" default="" selected="">-- Select --</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectComment.RAGStatusId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ProjectComment.RAGStatusId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RAGStatusId"><option value="" default="" selected="">-- Select --</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectComment.StatusComment" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectComment.StatusComment" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectComment.StatusComment" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectComment.EOQ" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectComment.EOQ" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProjectComment.EOQ" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The original Create.cshtml.cs action:

```
        [BindProperty]
        public ProjectComment ProjectComment { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["ProjectId"] = new SelectList(_context.Project.Where(a => a.IsArchived == false), "Id", "ProjectName");
            ViewData["RAGStatusId"] = new SelectList(_context.RAGStatus.Where(a => a.IsActive == true), "Id", "RAGStatusName");
            return Page();
        }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.ProjectComment.Add(ProjectComment);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
```

The modified Create.cshtml.cs OnGet action:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            ProjectComment = await _context.ProjectComment
                .Include(p => p.Project)
                .Include(p => p.RAGStatus).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (ProjectComment == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
```

When modifying the action the way I did it, the page is not displayed anymore (404 error).
I would like to populate the create form with the data from the last entry in the database. If there is no comment, the create page would only populate the name of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to Burak for providing the above solution, which works when you want to display the last row in the table. This helped me solving my issue by using the same approach and finding the record based on the Id of the record. 
I have amended the code from the Create.cshtml.cs file as follows:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id, int projectid)
        {
            //This will find the "ProjectComment" object.
            var projectComment = _context.ProjectComment.Find(id);

            //This will display the 'ProjectComment' on the page 
            ProjectComment = projectComment;
            if (id == null)
            {
                ProjectComment = projectComment; 

                ViewData["ProjectId"] = new SelectList(_context.Project, "Id", "ProjectName", projectid);


                return Page();
            }
            ViewData["ProjectId"] = new SelectList(_context.Project, "Id", "ProjectName");
            return Page();
        }
```

I am using the `int projectid` to populate the drop down menu of the project when there is no comment create yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending the "id" parameter to your post action I guess.

So could you please try to adding this line under your `form` tag:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="ProjectComment.Id" name="id" value="ProjectComment.Id" />
```

Comment: Thanks. This brought me further. However, I am now receiving the error 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ProjectComment' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.' This is due to the fact that the Id is auto-generated and unique. How can I get around that?

Comment: So do you want to insert data to a primary key column?

Comment: I want to populate the other fields only. The primary key column should be auto generated.

Comment: If you are trying to reach the values of the last record in your database, then you should change your approach. Try to find the last record by using: int max = db.ProjectComment .Max(p => p.Id);

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new to coding. In which file would I do the search (in the Create.cshtml or Create.cshtml.cs)? How would I display the content of the last comment in the Create.cshtml? Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: Just to be sure I have to ask one more time, in your Create.cshtml view, you would like to show user the contents of the last comment to your user. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, the contents from the last comment, so that the user can use the data to create the new comment. Therefore, the Id and the LastUpdateDate field would be "new" although all other fields may be the same (or slightly amended by the user).

Comment: Okay, for a clear answer, I might have to add another answer to this page, and if it is a correct answer, then I will delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reach the last record of your `ProjectComment` table. 
There are more than one methods to find the last record of your data table. But lets keep it simple.

You have an integer based identity column, which is **Auto Increment**. So you can simply use below methods to reach out the last created data of your table.

In your `OnGetAsync()` method:

```
//maxId will be the maximum value of "Id" columns. Which means that the maximum value is the last recorded value.
int maxId = _context.ProjectComment.Max(i => i.Id);

//And this line will bring you the last recorded "ProjectComment" object.
var projectComment = _context.ProjectComment.Find(maxId); 

//You can assign it to your above 'ProjectComment' property if you want to.. 
ProjectComment = projectComment
```

Now, since you've find the last recorded data in your database, you can use that object.

Comment: Hello Burak, I finally had time to test your solution. It works fine to get the last record. However, I need the last record for the project I am adding comments to. So there is an additional constraint I need: The last ProjectComment for the project (ProjectId) of the displayed comment. How can I add that constraint when I navigate from the index page which lists all my comments for all projects grouped by client?